# Retrieving branches from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, traversal, trie

I have a python nested dictionary (basically a trie structure) with sentences as branches - each node is a word. Something like this:
[image]

What is the most efficient way to retrieve all branches from root to the tips (sentences)? That is, I want to have all the possible sentences (I have a dog, I have a shotgun, I don't like Elvis). Branch (sentence) length in not a fixed value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do a depth first search and recursively yield the tokens of the sentence.
For example, using a generator:

```
def yield_sentences(node):
    if node.is_leaf():
        yield node.word
    else:
        for child in node.children:
            for sentence in yield_sentences(child):
                yield '{} {}'.format(node.word, sentence)
```

Usage:

```
>>> class Node(object):
...     def __init__(self, word, *children):
...             self.word = word
...             self.children = children
...     def is_leaf(self):
...             return not self.children
... 
>>> tree = Node('I', Node('have', Node('a', Node('dog'), Node('shotgun'))), Node("don't", Node('like', Node('Elvis'))))
>>> #tree is now your example tree
>>> list(yield_sentences(tree))
['I have a dog', 'I have a shotgun', "I don't like Elvis"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do it is a depth first search using memoization to optimize already parsed branch.

To do this, the simplest way is to store in each node, all the parent nodes preformatted. For instance the node `a` would have `I have`, the node `dog` would have `I have a`, etc.

This way, you will be able to extract all branches in a `O(n)` complexity, with n is the nodes count. However this requires a little modification of the structure.

For instance

```
class Node(dict):

    def __init__(self,parent,value,parent_str):
        self.parent      = parent
        self.value       = value
        self.children    = {}
        parent.children[value] = self
        self.parent_str  = parent_str+' '+value

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.parent_str+' '+value

    def addChild(self,value):
        Node(self,value,self.parent_str)
```